# Como fazer uma requisição http no Angular, e ter funções que retornam todos elementos do JSON ou apenas um passado por parametro?

Tags: angularjs

Eu sou novo no Angular e Ionic,
e eu quero construir uma factory que recebe um JSON do googleapis,
e contém duas funções, uma retorna todos os elementos, e outro que retorna o elemento que é passado o índice por parâmetro.

Eu estou tentando, assim:

Factory:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('Noticias', function($http,$q) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();                
        $http.get("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load", { params: { "v": "1.0", "q": "http://www.furg.br/bin/rss/noticias.php", "num":"10" } })
          .success(function(data) {
              entries = data.responseData.feed.entries;
              deferred.resolve(entries);
          })
          .error(function(data) {
              console.log("ERROR: " + data);
          });

  var noticias =  deferred.promise;
  console.log(noticias);
  return {
    all: function() {
      return noticias;
    },
    remove: function(noticia) {
      noticias.splice(noticias.indexOf(noticia), 1);
    },
    get: function(noticiaId) {
      for (var i = 0; i < noticias.length; i++) {
        if (noticias[i].id === parseInt(noticiaId)) {
          return noticias[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
});
```

Eu obtive isso no console, mas eu quero o apenas o "value"
[image: console]

Comment: acho que isso pode te ajudar, tanto quanto me ajudou: https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ionic-starter-eventmaps-tablet

Comment: você pode acessar a propriedade `seuobjeto.value[0]`, no caso creio que seja: `noticia.value`, que retorna uma coleção: `noticia.value[0], noticia.value[1] ...`

Comment: se for para exibir o erro deve ser : `data.value`, que retorna uma coleção: `data.value[0], data.value[1] ...`

Comment: o seu método tem algumas coisas meio desnecessárias... tipo para que fazer um for e sair na primeira chamada? basta fazer isso: noticias[0].id, que eu saiba todas as ids serão inteiras. e para consulta, passe a id como parâmetro para buscar somente aquela notícia.

Comment: olha esse exemplo tem tudo que você precisa: 
http://cacodaemon.de/index.php?id=51

Comment: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/find?v=1.0&q=termo+Buscado

Answer (score 2):

***Solução Encontrada :***
Baseada em: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33023283/5424391

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('Noticias', function($http,$q) {

  var noticias = $http.get("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load", { params: { "v": "1.0", "q": "http://www.furg.br/bin/rss/noticias.php", "num":"20" } })
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.data.responseData.feed.entries;
    });

  return {
    all: function() {
      return noticias.then(function(array){
        return array;
      });
    },
    get: function(noticiaIndex) {
    return noticias.then(function(array) {
        return array[parseInt(noticiaIndex)];        
    });
  }
  };
});
```